# Is there a way to copy Google Earth place names as text?

Tags: compare, copy-paste, google-earth, kmz

I'm new to python and doing a work project that involves juggling a lot (5-10k) of "places" (polygons representing regions) in google earth. As such, I wanted to run a list compare between the places I have in google earth against a txt file list of places I *should* have. The only problem is that I cannot seem to find a way to copy paste or otherwise capture the name text of the google earth places. Copying with control c or right click copy copies them as a KMZ file, or when pasted into a text editor gives the full source from their "properties" tab. I'm fairly confident in manipulating and comparing the lists once I have the data in that format, but could really use some help in attaining it as such.

Answer (score 0):

First right-click on saved places in Google Earth and save as KML (text) file.

Next, you can use Python to extract the place names from the KML file.
Here's some sample code using [pykml](https://pythonhosted.org/pykml/) module to parse out the place names.

```python
from pykml import parser

with open('places.kml') as f:
  root = parser.parse(f).getroot()

# iterate over each placemark
for pm in root.Document.Placemark:
    name = pm.name.text
    print(name)
```